# How to identify if legit or fake Babolat Pure Strik 16x19 racket

Tags: tennis, racket

I am a new tennis player and would like to take it further. Currently I am planning on buying a tennis racket but I can only afford 2nd hand racket due to financial status. I saw a post online which is a Babolat Pure Strike 16x19 and was planning on buying it. According to the owner, he bought it but hasn't been used (due to unknown reasons) and decided to sell it. At first everything looks good but as I ask for more pictures, some designs are a bit off like the bumper guard color, string, grip. Can someone enlighten me about this? Thank you.

**ADDITIONAL**

I have checked and compared more designs via online and found additional off designs from the racket, example is the paint job to the sides. It is not like a semi smooth curve line but rather two separate lines. Middle part above grip, there should be like a slope but no slope in image.

[image: Sides]
[image: Tension]
[image: Should be curved with slope]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because identifying specific objects is not within the scope of our expertise, and does not support future reference.

Comment: [See here](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/939/generalising-the-off-topicality-of-autograph-identification-questions) for comparable discussion of why such a question is closed.